# nested list comprehension to populate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

Objective: Compute some bivariate polynomial e.g. f(x,y) = sin(x^2 + y^2) for x ∈ [-1,1] and y ∈ [-1,1] and stick values in a dataframe.

What I have...

```
def sunbrero(x,y):
  return np.sin(x**2 + y**2)

lower=-1
upper=1
length=1000
X = np.linspace(lower, upper, num=length)
Y = np.linspace(lower, upper, num=length)
Z = pd.DataFrame(index=X,columns=Y)
# [[sunbrero(x,y) for x in X] for y in Y]
for y in Y:
  Z[y] = [sunbrero(x,y) for x in X]
```

What I'm hoping to do is something that replaces...

```
for y in Y:
  Z[y] = [sunbrero(x,y) for x in X]
```

...with something like...

```
[[Z[y] = sunbrero(x,y) for x in X] for y in Y]
```

But obviously the above doesn't work.

I know that this works...

```
Z = [[sunbrero(x,y) for x in X] for y in Y]
```

...but it creates a list of lists rather than a dataframe.

Note 1: if others think a 2D vector is more sensible c.f dataframe, I'm open to that as well.

Note 2: I don't think lambda functions work as it only allows one variable to be defined. Happy to be corrected.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more reasonable to use the function application methods provided by Pandas, which are specifically optimized for this kind of operations, as opposed to an external list comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

I think the more Panda-esque way of doing this would be to calculate the values *first* and put them into a dataframe afterwards, not vice versa. Performing the calculations in a list comprehension does not put the internal vector optimizations of Numpy and Pandas to good use.

Instead, you can make use of Numpy's broadcasting to get the matrix first:

```py
length = 5

X = np.linspace(lower, upper, num=length)
Y = np.linspace(lower, upper, num=length)

result = sunbrero(X[:, None], Y)
```

```py
array([[0.90929743, 0.94898462, 0.84147098, 0.94898462, 0.90929743],
       [0.94898462, 0.47942554, 0.24740396, 0.47942554, 0.94898462],
       [0.84147098, 0.24740396, 0.        , 0.24740396, 0.84147098],
       [0.94898462, 0.47942554, 0.24740396, 0.47942554, 0.94898462],
       [0.90929743, 0.94898462, 0.84147098, 0.94898462, 0.90929743]])
```

and put that in a dataframe like so:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(result, index=X, columns=Y)
```

```py
          -1.0      -0.5       0.0       0.5       1.0
-1.0  0.909297  0.948985  0.841471  0.948985  0.909297
-0.5  0.948985  0.479426  0.247404  0.479426  0.948985
 0.0  0.841471  0.247404  0.000000  0.247404  0.841471
 0.5  0.948985  0.479426  0.247404  0.479426  0.948985
 1.0  0.909297  0.948985  0.841471  0.948985  0.909297
```

Comment: Thank you. This is even better. I've learnt something new today.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[sunbrero(x,y) for x in X] for y in Y])
```

Comment: Thank you. This response is the solution to my question. As @fsimonjetz pointed out in their response, there's a better way to take advantage of numpy vector opt.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your list comprehension, then have pandas create a dataframe from a list of lists, for example:

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists)
```

to get

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```